# Using view in several pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

everybody! I have a view (let's say x) that I want to use at some parts of several pages (let's say y, z, t). The action (let's say a) that called from view (x) calls a web service that returns me an id (let's say i) and  returns the same view (x) again. And in the pages (y, z and t) I want to do different things using this id (i). How can I realise this scenario? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep, you've succeeded: my brain's synapses are fried!  In other words, I believe there should be an easier way to describe your problem.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find another way to tell my problem :/

Comment: There's no easy way to do this or no easy way for us to explain. I have a feeling that lots of MVC concepts&features could be used here, like Partial Views = RenderPartial(), action rendering with RenderAction(), Post-Redirect-Get pattern, etc..You should educate yourself on these subjects and then you might find the answer to your question. Probably you will be able to formulate it better also.

Comment: I'm with @Thomas - you need to explain it better and you definitely could with a bit of code. If you can't give us code, give us a scenario with that we can actually understand rather than abstract stuff like view 'x', action 'a', pages 'y', 'z', & 't' and web service that returns an id 'i'.

Comment: Really sorry @Charlino... The code you that you expect me is not short enough to share, and if I do this I think it will not be helpful than this version... Scenario? That's what I'm trying to do. Do you think it will be more helpful if I alter "a" with "FileUpload"? If you want the question like an analyze document, I think noone will read this looong text :) Happy to find someone that understand my problem. Really I tried to explain myself in a more efficient way, but I couldn't. Thanks for your interest. // Thanks @mare, I'll try to put in practice your suggestions

Comment: @anilca - exactly, explain it more verbosely like 'I have a form inside a partial view which deals with file uploading. I want to use this file upload partial on various different views. When the file upload form posts to the upload action it calls a webservice which returns an int... etc etc. Even some pesudo code would help people formulate what your are trying to do better in their minds.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the view (x) just be a form that you control with AJAX (JQuery) from each of the parent views (y,z,t)?